# Counting geometries which intersect another geometry using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, st-intersects, st-union

I'm trying to calculate the total area for each layer I have within a specific area and count the geometries which intersects with that specific area.

I can calculate the area and the results seem plausible, but how do I count the objects?

```
SELECT st_area(ST_Transform(ST_Setsrid((st_intersection(
        st_union(st_makevalid(object.postgis_area_geometry)),
        specific_area_geometry
    )), 3857), 4326)::geography),
       layer.name

FROM    object
        LEFT JOIN layer ON layer.id = object.layer_id
WHERE
        ST_ISVALID(object.postgis_area_geometry)
GROUP BY 
        layer.id;
```

for instance:

[image]

Here I have 4 Layers. Each layer has just one Geometry, just to keep it simple.

```
Object 1: Black 100 m2 = Layer 1
Object 2: Blue 70 m2 =   Layer 2
Object 3: Green 120 m2 = Layer 3
Object 4: Purple 70 m2 = Layer 4

The red square is the specific area within I want to know the total area of each layer.

So I want the following results:

Layer 1 = 35 m2, count = 1
Layer 2 = 10 m2, count = 1
Layer 3 = 35 m2, count = 1
Layer 4 = 0  m2, count = 0
```

Comment: Any query with an ST_SetSRID is immediately suspect, especially in the context of an ST_Transform. You seem to have the IDs encoded already, so isn't this just a `count(*)` issue?

Comment: I just need to convert from EPSG 3857 to 4326 to get the area in square meter

Comment: If the data is already in 3857, then the SetSRID is a waste of computing resources. If you haven't set any SRID, then you should do that first (permanently, so it isn't necessary in subsequent queries)

Comment: Problem was that my postgis_area_geometry column is auto generated from another column I have and the default srid is 4326 which is wrong in my case because my data is in 3857, so this is because I had to use setSrid. I just fix this, thx.

Comment: Please don't place an answer in the Question. If the actual solution is different than the correct answer, you can add an Answer (acknowledging, but not thanking, the contributor(s)), with the as-built solution.

Comment: He gave me a more detailed answer, and it contains what I need to solve my problem. It's the inner join on st_intersects.

Comment: Right. But we use a Question/Answer model, and answers don't belong in Questions. The edit can be rolled back, but others can't add an Answer for you. We don't do thanks here as a matter of policy see the [Help Center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a combination of [ST_Intersects](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) and [ST_Intersection](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html). The count you're doing doesn't make a lot of sense to me, since you'd only ever get either 1 or 0. For that reason, you could just use `ST_Intersects(a.geom,b.geom)` for a `boolean` return of either `True` or `False`. And as per geozelot's comment, you can cast `bool` to `int` to get the output as you specify. I've also included how you'd get the full count of intersecting features.

I've created two layers; `gisse` (5 pink features) and `gisse2` (1 blue feature), both using `SRID: 4326`:

[image]

```
select id,st_area(st_transform(geom,3857)) from gisse order by id
```

Gives:

| id | st_area |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 571990204493.9556 |
| 2 | 782180369787.4814 |
| 3 | 717504875654.8381 |
| 4 | 645453473213.9517 |
| 5 | 683918275314.2 |

To generate polygons showing the parts of table 1 that intersect with table 2:

```
create view theintersects as 
select a.id,
st_area(st_transform(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom),3857)),
st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom) from gisse a 
inner join gisse2 b on st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)
order by a.id
```

Computed features in yellow:
[image]

If I instead want to get the statistics without the geometry field, including non-intersecting rows:

```
select a.id,
st_area(st_transform(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom),3857)),
st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)::int as intersect_count
from gisse a left join gisse2 b on st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)
order by a.id
```

| id | st_area | intersect_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 56153016337.158646 | 1 |
| 3 | 261289632649.45654 | 1 |
| 4 | 49506223558.761505 | 1 |
| 5 | 197914797339.4397 | 1 |

If you just want the count of features from `gisse` that intersect with `gisse2`, execute:

```
select count(a.id) as intersecting_features
from gisse a inner join gisse2 b on st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)
```

Result:

| intersecting_features |
| --- |
| 4 |

Comment: I just edit my question with a little more details of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Sure, I'll expand on the answer. What you want is a combination of ST_Intersects and ST_Intersection

Comment: FYI: PostgreSQL happily casts `BOOL` to `INT` and *vice versa*, i.e. `SELECT ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)::INT`.

Comment: Thanks @geozelot - updated the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just want to count all objects, for each layer which intersects with that specific area and calculate the total area for each layer within the specific area. It does not make sense with only one object in a layer, but I have a lot of objects in each layer. I think I got this, see my edit. The purpose of this is that this specific area is a user input. So basically he wants to get a report about what's going on in an area he selects. In this case I show him the number of objects for each layer and the total area for each layer.